# How can we find out that if a replication job or normal replication is running at a particular time

Tags: sql-server

How can we find out that if a replication job or normal replication is running at a particular time. Please,help to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to monitor replication you need to use the Replication Monitor tool.

The following article describes how to use this tool.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151780(SQL.90).aspx

Cheers, John

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are referring to Microsoft SQL Server Replication, here is a quick method to observe replication status.

In the database hosting the publication go to Object Explorer tree view:
1. Open Local Publications folder under Replication
2. Right Click on a publication select Log Reader Status

The log reader agent will be reading the transaction log and populating the distribution database with the changes that need to be pushed to subscriber.

An active log agent will show in the status window messages such as:
63 transactions with 439 command were delivered

Nevertheless, this diagram explains pretty quickly how the transactional replication works.
Replication Architecture (BOL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

In MS SQL if you need to programatically check a job status (for example from a monitoring tool) you can fire off the following query. For push replication the target would be the replication distributor (or the publisher if you haven't scaled out distribution). For pull replication the target would be the replication subscriber.

```
EXEC msdb..sp_help_job @job_name='<job name here>', @job_aspect = N'job'
```

You can find the job name under the SQL server agent for the distributor/subscriber.

You're looking for column 26 ("current_execution_status"), which will be "1" if the job is currently running.

Answer (score 0):

sp_distcounters tells you the current status.
If the count of delivered commands changes for a given subscription then your replication is working, else not.